# Populating a spinner used in more than two activities

Tags: android-actionbar, spinner, android

I have an action bar spinner and two Activities in my app. The spinner, which is populated from a database, needs to be visible in both my activities. How should I generate it without duplicating my code? Should I create a static  method or something else?

```
private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
private List<String> listUniqueCat;
int selectedPos;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_joke_details);
    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    //this method returns list of strings from a database
    listUniqueCat = mDbHelper.getUniqueCategories();

    // create an array adapter to popluate dropdown list
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getBaseContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listUniqueCat);

    // enable dropdown list naaavigation in action bar
    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    // defining navigation listiner
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId)
        {
            selectedPos = getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "selected index is "+ selectedPos ,
                                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return false;
        }
    };

    // setting dropdown items and item navigation listener for action bar
    getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);
}
```

Comment: Well one way would be to create abstract BaseActivity, then extend it with your two activities. In your BaseActivity onCreate you would implement logic for populating actionbar spinner from DB.

Comment: but then I would have to override the methods anyway

Comment: In your activities, you always override onCreate anyways, and this way you would avoid duplicated code.

Comment: every activity already extends Activity, multiple inheritance is not allowed

Comment: @Frugo use `EveryAcivity extends BaseActivity` and `BaseActivity extends Activity` this is called multilevel inheritance not multiple.

Comment: Declare listUniqueCat as static variable.call this in activity B and set it in spinner adapter

Comment: one of my activities already extends ListActivity

Comment: @hemanthkumar extending BaseActivity is better solution than using static variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create one BaseActivity with tabs like

```
abstract public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {

}
```

and all other activities extends BaseActivity

small example for you

BaseActivity.java

```
abstract public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements TabListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
   ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    // add tabs to actionbar
   actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB 1")
        .setTabListener(this));
   actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB 2")
        .setTabListener(this));

  }

}
```

FirstActivity.java

```
 public class FirstActivity extends BaseActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
 }

 @Override
 public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        tab.getText() + " selected in FirstActivity",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }

   @Override
   public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

 }
```

SecondActivity.java

```
 public class SecondActivity extends BaseActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
   public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        tab.getText() + " selected in SectondActivity",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

   @Override
   public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

 }
```

Comment: I do NOT have tabs, just an action bar spinner

Comment: this is just example..you have to change as per your requirement.

Comment: NOTE: if you are using BaseActivity pattern, do not misuse it for functionality that doesnt belong in activity class (like utility methods).

Comment: You mean do not use methods of `non-activity` class in to BaseActivity..aren't you ?